# writing own directive with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with showing error message when the user enters a wrong number. I tried to write my own directive for that but i m getting an error
"Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".
I m totally a newbie, just trying to learn directives. Any idea where did i made a mistake or how should i made it ?

Template :

```
   <div ng-controller="performanceController">

<input  type="number" name="performance" class="typo-xl-l input-power"
       ng-model="performance" min-performance="10" max-performance="30">
    <span id = "errorText"></span>

</div>
```

Controller :

```
    'use strict';


angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/inputView.html'
          })

    }])
.controller('performanceController', function($scope) {

})
.directive("maxPerformance", [function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          var limit = parseInt(attrs.maxPerformance);

            if (this.value.length > limit) {
              document.getElementById('errorText').innerText("wrong number");
            }

        }
      }
    }])
    .directive("minPerformance", [function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          var limit = parseInt(attrs.minPerformance);

          if (this.value.length < limit) {
            document.getElementById('errorText').innerText("wrong number");
          }

        }
      }
    }]);
```

UPDATE :

```
   .directive("maxPerformance", [function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel', //this will make ng-model attribute compulsary on directive element.
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) { //injected ngModel here 4th parameter
          var limit = parseInt(attrs.maxPerformance);
          angular.element(elem).on("keydown", function() {
          if (ngModel.$viewValue.length > limit) {
            document.getElementById('errorText').innerText("wrong number");
          }
          });
        }
      }
    }])
    .directive("minPerformance", [function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {  //injected ngModel here 4th parameter
          var limit = parseInt(attrs.minPerformance);
          angular.element(elem).on("keydown", function() {
          if (ngModel.$viewValue.length < limit) {
            document.getElementById('errorText').innerText("wrong number");
          }
          });
        }
      }
    }]);
```

Still not working..

Answer (score 0):

While getting the value of ngModel inside your directive you could actually have `require: ngModel` option inside directive which will give `ngModelController` value inside link function. And then easily you could fetch value of it using `ngModel.$viewValue`

```
.directive("maxPerformance", [function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel', //this will make ng-model attribute compulsary on directive element.
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) { //injected ngModel here 4th parameter
      var limit = parseInt(attrs.maxPerformance);

        if (ngModel.$viewValue.length > limit) {
          document.getElementById('errorText').innerText = "wrong number";
        }

    }
  }
}])
.directive("minPerformance", [function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {  //injected ngModel here 4th parameter
      var limit = parseInt(attrs.minPerformance);

      if (ngModel.$viewValue.length < limit) {
        document.getElementById('errorText').innerText = "wrong number";
      }

    }
  }
}]);
```

**Update**

Rather going for creating custom directive, you could handle such a small thing by using `ng-min` & `ng-max` attributes on the `input` element which is of `type="number"`.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="performanceController">
    <input type="number" name="performance" class="typo-xl-l input-power" ng-model="performance" min="10" max="30" />
    <span id="errorText" ng-show="myForm.performance.$error.min || myForm.performance.$error.max">
      Wrong Number
    </span>
</form>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9jUuOMwPi3ffjN9BtGk?p=preview)

Comment: @AkinDönmez did you inject `ngModel` as 4th parameter inside link function

Comment: yeah i check now i dont get any errors but it is not working.. debug is also no working so i guess i need a event listener here like keypress or sth like that

Comment: .directive("minPerformance", [function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs,ngModel) {
          var limit = parseInt(attrs.minPerformance);
          angular.element(elem).on("keydown", function() {
          if (ngModel.$viewValue.length < limit) {
            document.getElementById('errorText').innerHTML("wrong number")

          }
          });
        }
      }

Comment: YOu need to wrap that code in function and call that function inside some event like `change` or something like that..

Comment: @AkinDönmez why you didn't went for `ng-minlength` & `ng-maxlength` directive

Comment: For the thing you want tonachive can be found without directive..do you want directive version of it..?

Comment: @AkinDönmez basically in your code `document.getElementById('errorText').innerText("wrong number")` should be `document.getElementById('errorText').innerText = "wrong number";` as `.innerText` needs string, its not parameterize method http://plnkr.co/edit/1t80h2XUUjZX97SP5cGj?p=preview